# cakePHP3: How to write a clean MVC code?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to write my code according to the MVC paradigm in cakePHP3:

I have a formular to register an owner but as an owner is basically a user with additional informations, I have 2 SQL tables; one for a user pointing to an owner, and one for the owner.

The idea here is that a user is not necessary an owner.

So I currently wrote the code, which do what I want in the add action in the OwnerController.php.

```
public function add() {

    $this->loadModel('Users');

    $user = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data);
    $owner = $this->Owners->newEntity($this->request->data);

    $addDatas = [ 
            'owner_id' => 'id',
            'email'     => $owner['email'],
            'role'  => 'owner',
            'token'     => md5(time() . '-' . uniqid()),
    ];

    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $addDatas);

    $owner->users = [$user];

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Owners->validate($owner)) {
            if ($this->Owners->save($owner)) {
                $email = new Email('gmail');
                $email->template('activationLink')
                    ->emailFormat('text')
                    ->to($owner['email'])
                        ->from('myemail@monsite.fr')
                    ->subject(__('Votre inscription sur monsite.fr'))
                    ->viewVars(['user' => $user, 'id' => $user['id']])
                    ->send();

                $this->Flash->success(__("Merci de vous être enregistré. un email a été envoyé à {0} pour activer votre compte", $owner['email']));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__("Impossible de vous enregistrer, veuillez corriger les erreurs"));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Impossible de vous enregistrer, veuillez corriger les erreurs"));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('owner'));
}
```

now, I would like to write it like that:

```
public function add() {

    $owner = $this->Owners->newEntity($this->request->data);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($owner->addOwner($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__("Merci de vous être enregistré. un email a été envoyé à {0} pour activer votre compte", $owner['email']));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Impossible de vous enregistrer, veuillez corriger les erreurs"));
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('owner'));
}
```

And so, I would have an addOwner() action in my Owner.php and let him to do everything needed.

My problem is that I don't see in the documentation how can I have access to my User model from my Owner model and more precisely, how to make the User model validate and save its record.

Maybe I'm wrong but I don't really see this way to code in the tutorials.

Owner.php

```
class Owner extends Entity {

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * @var array
     */
        protected $_accessible = [
            'email' => true,
            'phone' => true,
            'company' => true,
            'tva_number' => true,
            'address' => true,
            'postcode' => true,
            'city' => true,
            'users' => true,
        ];


        public function addOwner($data = array()) {

           // This is where I want to create both the owner and the user
           // as the owner is basically a user with additional contact infos.
           // But how to access the User model here to realize the validation
           // as save the record?
        }
    }
```

User.php

```
class User extends Entity {

/**
 * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'username' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'first_name' => true,
        'last_name' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'role' => true,
        'owner' => true,
        'sites_user' => true,
        'active' => true,
        'token' => true,
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($password) {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }

}
```

UsersTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Owners', [
        'foreignKey' => 'owner_id',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('SitesUsers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'sites_users_id',
    ]);
}
```

OwnersTable.php

```
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->table('owners');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'owner_id',
    ]);
}
```

Can you show me the relationship between the two ?

Comment: Can you show the models plz ?

Comment: @may saghira, yes, I've edited my post for that.

Comment: where the relation between the two models ? i don't see any belongsTo or hasMany ?

Comment: ok, sorry, there are in table models. I edit the post

Answer (score 0):

First, you should normalize your database (on your Owners entity I can see you have users which is an array of users).

Also, use CakePHP 3 naming conventions: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html

Then, since this seems to be your first steps into CakePHP 3, you should try  bake (CakePHP Scaffolding) your application.

Bake (CakePHP Scaffolding): http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/usage.html

Baking an is a great way to see how you should start coding in CakePHP 3.

Hope this helps.